# Remove everything after a string in a data frame column with missing values

Tags: regex, r, string, gsub, strsplit

I have a data frame resembling the extract below:

```
Observation Identifier   Value
Obs001      ABC_2001     54
Obs002      ABC_2002     -2
Obs003                   1
Obs004                   1 
Obs005      Def_2001/05
```

I would like to transform this data frame into a data frame where portions of the string after the *"_"* sign would be removed: as illustrated below:

```
Observation Identifier_NoTime   Value
Obs001      ABC                 54
Obs002      ABC                 -2
Obs003                          1
Obs004                          1 
Obs005      Def
```

I tried experimenting with `strsplit`, `gsub` and `sub` as discussed here but cannot force those commends to work. I have to account for the fact that:

1. Column has missing values and I want to leave them where they are
2. String "_" is located in different places in the variable
3. I also want to leave the rest of the data frame the way it is

Comment: did you try `sub("_\\S+","",string,perl=T)` ?

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm. Would you care to elaborate on that?

Comment: then i make it as an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try the below `sub` command to remove all the non-space characters from `_` symbol.

```
sub("_\\S*", "", string)
```

**Explanation:**

- `_` Matches a literal `_` symbol.
- `\S*` Matches zero or more non-space characters.

**OR**

This would remove all the characters from `_` symbol,

```
sub("_.*", "", string)
```

**Explanation:**

- `_` Matches a literal `_` symbol.
- `.*` Matches any character zero or more times.

Comment: why not `sub("_.+","",string,perl=T)` ?

Comment: Why not `sub("_.*","",string,perl=T)`  :-) ?

Comment: So in the case of `\S` what is the `S` for and what are the other options?

Comment: `\s` would match any space characters `space,tab,newline,carriage return`. `\S` would does the reverse operation. Don't consider \ and `S` as separate ones.

Comment: `perl=T` is not a requirement for this.