# Regex matching all characters from the beginning of the string to the first underscore

Tags: regex, r, substring

I am trying to substring elements of a vector to only keep the part before the FIRST underscore. I am a bit of a newbie with taking substrings and don't fully understand all regex yet. I am close to the answer, I can get the part that I want to delete but still don't see how to get the opposite part. Any help and/or explanation of regex is appreciated!

my vector looks like the following, with multiple underscores in some elements

```
v = c("WL_Alk", "LQ_Frac_C_litter_origin", "MI_Nr_gat", "SED_C_N", "WL_CO2", "WL_S")
```

my desired output looks like

```
v_short = c("WL", "LQ", "MI", "SED", "WL", "WL")
```

The code that gets me the part I want to delete is `sub("^[^_]*", "", v)`. I think I have to do something with $ in regex because `sub("[_$]", "", v)` deletes the first underscore, but I can't get it to delete the part behind it. Even with the regex helpfile I don't fully understand the meaning of ^, $ and * yet, so explanation on those is also appreciated!

Comment: Well, at any rate, my answer shows how to actually *keep*, not just *remove* the part after a "string". [*R removing everything after a string in a data frame column with missing values*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26611922/r-removing-everything-after-a-string-in-a-data-frame-column-with-missing-values) only dwells on the unnecessary  string chunk removal approach.

Comment: Sorry, I could not find that (duplicate) question before, that one is very helpful too! I only found others where the regex wasn't explained and didn't exactly match with my question.

Comment: It is because the title of that question is off the roof. You know, a good title means more reputation for the OP. Please also consider changing yours to something like *Regex matching all characters from the beginning of the string to the first underscore*, or something like that. Something that other people would look for.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: good title! I am always struggling with those

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
> v = c("WL_Alk", "LQ_Frac_C_litter_origin", "MI_Nr_gat", "SED_C_N", "WL_CO2", "WL_S")
> sub("_.*", "", v)
[1] "WL"  "LQ"  "MI"  "SED" "WL"  "WL"
```

The `"_.*"`  pattern matches the first `_` and `.*` matches any 0+ characters up to the end of string greedily (that is, grabs them at one go).

With *stringr* **`str_extract`**, you can use your pattern:

```
> library(stringr)
> v_short = str_extract(v, "^[^_]*")
> v_short
[1] "WL"  "LQ"  "MI"  "SED" "WL"  "WL"
```

The `^[^_]*` pattern matches the beginning of the string and 0 or more characters other than `_`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! This really helps and works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly

```
gsub("(.*?)(_.*)","\\1",v,  perl = TRUE)
```

Explanation:

`(.*?)` the first capturing group;

`(_.*)` the second capturing group;

`\\1` return the first capturing group;

Comment: The output is `[1] "WL"               "LQ_Frac_C_litter" "MI_Nr"            "SED_C"            "WL"               "WL" ` because `(.*)(_.*)` matches the *last* `_`.

Comment: Make it `non-greedy` as `(.*?)(_.*)` and it will work

Comment: @rock321987: Yes, that should work then. However, the pattern would not be that clean and efficient.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes..i am just encouraging different answer

Comment: Thanks! Do I understand it correctly if I interpret `(.*?)` to be everything before the first underscore, and `(_.*)` any 0+ characters behind it? What does the `"\\1"` stand for?

Comment: @Ciska `\\1` is the first capturing group..you can understand `(.*?)` that way..The `?` makes it `non-greedy` means the matching will stop as soon as first underscore is found

Comment: Yes, @Ciska, you aright. I created two "capturing groups" (putting a regex between the square brackets), and the "\\1" return the first group only; if you go for "\\2" you will get the second group instead.

Comment: This explanation really helps! I finally start to see how it works. Thanks again!

Comment: As I asaid, this solution is overly complicated for the current scenario. Regexes with capturing groups lose in performance to regexes without them. Mixing lazy and greedy quantifiers is not welcome, I'd suggest using `perl=T` then (PCRE is known to handle those scenarios well).

Comment: Machine performance: you are right! I use a lot of "capturing groups" for the programmer, as a form of "cognitive economy". I edit it with the "perl" flag

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it.

Either use `^[^_]+` and match string before first `_`. [Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dF1jR4/1)

OR

Select the part after first `_` using `\_.+$` and eliminate it. [Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dF1jR4/2)