# Why is visible column missing from data frame dimensions?

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have a very long data frame named df.alt.alleles looks like this (~9 million rows):

```
                    AC
1:123456789_G/C     5
1:139406018_A/T     21
1:156902649_C/G     47
1:189027493_A/G     23
```

When I find the class I am told it is a dataframe:

```
class(df.alt.alleles)
##"data.frame"
```

When I query the dimensions I am told there is only one column though when viewed there appears to be two columns.

```
dim(df.alt.alleles)
##
```

I want to find all instances of _ and remove it and and everything after it in that column to produce a new data frame that looks like this (but for all 9 million rows):

```
                    AC
1:123456789         5
1:139406018         21
1:156902649         47
1:189027493         23
```

I have tried using:

```
sub("_\\S*", "", "df.alt.alleles")
```

As suggested here: [Remove everything after a string in a data frame column with missing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26611922/r-removing-everything-after-a-string-in-a-data-frame-column-with-missing-values)

This returns a character string with all the numbers in the "AC" column.

**Note:** Sorry if this is a terrible questions but I am a complete R novice and have searched high and low for an explanation for something which seems very basic. Apologies if the question is ill formatted I am completely new at this and I'll take on board any advice!

Comment: Because what appears to be a second column (first in the series) is actually row names. Try doing `df$whateverName <- row.names(df)`. And, perhaps also `row.names(df) <- NULL`. Then, you can operate on that column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you can see the issue and correction, I believe:

```
df
                AC
1:123456789_G/C  5
1:139406018_A/T 21
1:156902649_C/G 47
1:189027493_A/G 23

df$somename <- row.names(df)
df
                AC        somename
1:123456789_G/C  5 1:123456789_G/C
1:139406018_A/T 21 1:139406018_A/T
1:156902649_C/G 47 1:156902649_C/G
1:189027493_A/G 23 1:189027493_A/G

row.names(df) <- NULL
df
  AC        somename
1  5 1:123456789_G/C
2 21 1:139406018_A/T
3 47 1:156902649_C/G
4 23 1:189027493_A/G
```

Answer (score 0):

Using dplyr and tidyr:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  add_rownames("variant") %>%
  separate(variant, into = c("chr", "bp", "allele"), sep = "_|:", remove = FALSE)


# Source: local data frame [4 x 5]
# 
#           variant   chr        bp allele    AC
#             (chr) (chr)     (chr)  (chr) (int)
# 1 1:123456789_G/C     1 123456789    G/C     5
# 2 1:139406018_A/T     1 139406018    A/T    21
# 3 1:156902649_C/G     1 156902649    C/G    47
# 4 1:189027493_A/G     1 189027493    A/G    23
```